# How to make an equation for regular $n$-gon with rounded corners in polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates, polygons

I have an equation that allows me to draw a regular *n*-gon.

$$R(\theta) = \dfrac{r}{\cos\left(\theta-\dfrac{2\pi}{N}\left\lfloor\dfrac{N\theta+\pi}{2\pi}\right\rfloor\right)},
$$

where *r* is the radius of the inscribed circle and *N* is the number of corners of a polygon.

I have a problem to change this equation to make a polygon with a corner rounded with some radius $r_2$. Anyone has any idea how to approach it?

I attach links to images of what I mean as well as link to wolfram with the formula above.

Hexagon:
[image: Hexagon]

Hexagon with rounded corners:
[image: Hexagon with rounded corners]

[Wolfram Showcase](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=polarplot+R%2F%28cos%28theta-2*pi%2FN*floor%28%28N*theta%2Bpi%29%2F%282*pi%29%29%29%29%29%2C+theta+from+0+to+2pi+and+N%3D5+and+R%3D5)

Answer (score 0):

A heuristic attempt (that is it won't be *quite* a circle at the corner, and the radius might take some interpretation) would be to replace your existing $R(\theta)$ with a smoothed version $S$, such that
$$S(\theta)\approx {1\over 2n+1}\sum _{i=-n}^nS(\theta + i \Delta)$$ for some small value of $\theta$, roughly $r_2 \propto  \Delta$

Comment: Sadly I need it to be quite precise. I was thinking about equation of a circle with center described by some $r$ and angle $\alpha$, but I don't know how to combine those two, because circle will be only for specific angles.